# Why can I access gdal in my python 3.6 shell but not my django shell

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, gdal, geodjango

I have a django project that I want to use gdal in. I have installed all the dependencies and it works fine if I do:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> gdal
<module 'osgeo.gdal' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py'>
```

but when I do:

```
$python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

It appears both are using the same python so I am not sure what the problem is. Could it be a path problem?

Comment: What happens if you do `python3.6 manage.py shell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jonah Bishop suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491491/why-can-i-access-gdal-in-my-python-3-6-shell-but-not-my-django-shell/54990938#comment93853104_53491491), I was able to solve the problem by running:

```
python3 manage.py shell
```